# Distinct predicate in sql crashes Access

Tags: ms-access

I am writing a query in Access and it is very simple :

```
SELECT fieldName FROM table;
```

That works perfectly okay, however if I try the following query Access will not respond and crashes :

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM table;
```

**Note**: This is not the first time in the database I've used the distinct clause.

**Possibly of note:** the table that it is querying is another query and of the form --

```
SELECT * from otherTable where otherField IN 
                                         (SELECT otherField2 from otherTable2);
```

Does anyone have any clues as to what could cause this ?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify - I want to be able to edit the records returned from the last query in my original post but just want the results of the distinct query.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to re-use the editable query? Why not just write a second non-editable query using JOINs instead of IN that gives the same result?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your database is corrupt.  Try a compact & repair.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Nvm - my apologies for commenting before looking. That wasn't hard to find at all.

Comment: It was actually a very astute suggestions, since corrupted indexes can cause exactly this kind of inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

The IN keyword slows access down, particularly querying a query like you're trying to do. You could try a join instead, eg:

SELECT * FROM otherTable LEFT JOIN otherTable2 
ON otherTable.otherField=otherTable2.otherField2

Comment: The only issue with the join that I had is that it would not allow me to edit the records pulld in the query. Is there a way to fix that issue?

Comment: Actually, IN shouldn't be a problem here, as Jet/ACE will use the index on both sides. It's NOT IN that is problematic, in my experience, but you could definitely turn on Jet SHOWPLAN and find out for certain. But I do agree that a JOIN is preferable here where possible.

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN would only return the same recordset as your original query if otherTable2 only contains 0 or 1 records for every parent record in otherTable.  You could acheive the same results in all scenarios with

```
SELECT DISTINCT otherTable.*
FROM otherTable INNER JOIN otherTable2
  ON otherTable.otherField = otherTable2.otherField2
```

This will return an editable recordset.  I doubt the performance will be any different than the IN query.  It's something to try if the IN query is still crashing Access after the compact & repair.